# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using jasper to display report for my project...Actually i m trying to pass the parameters dynamically to jrxml template as i saw in the link given below but i couldnt.....There seems a problem in my code the error is

```
        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : C:\Users\db2admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConnectDB\src\sample_report.jrxml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:487)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:874)
    at ConnectDB.main(ConnectDB.java:65)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:110)
    ... 3 more
```

the jasper snippet is

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT reg, name FROM students");
JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);          

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("C:\\Users\\db2admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\
             ConnectDB\\src\\sample_report.jrxml", null, resultSetDataSource);
```

Finally the xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample_report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="b3b98795-b21f-4006-9295-5ef4248c84ea">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>

    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="reg" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6d6bff96-6dcb-4188-bdc0-5c23b2614b05" key="staticText-1" x="40" y="11" width="196" height="15"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c0267b29-e31b-4afd-a181-86bbcb4fb368" key="staticText-2" x="330" y="11" width="193" height="15"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Reg]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="4a1e6484-9610-421d-b4a4-f61d53458d9e" key="textField" x="47" y="6" width="173" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="01cb3d91-74e7-4594-aca0-605d1aa203a8" key="textField" x="330" y="6" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reg}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I referred this site
http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-dynamic-reports-from-databases-jasperreports-3.5

Plz help me with this!!!!

Comment: What version of *JR API* are you using?

Comment: The version is 4.7.1 bro!!!

Comment: Ah i got it... JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);                                          JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\db2admin\\Documents\\            NetBeansProjects\\ConnectDB\\src\\sample_report.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,        null, resultSetDataSource);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in ireport, review that your subreports are referencing to the .jasper file (not the jrxml).

If you are publising your report to the jasperreports-server, take in mind that it does a changes in the report definition referencing the jrxml files with a prefix (but not the jasper files).

Comment: this was the issue for me. Quite annoying to deal w/ these expression changes between server and local, really wish @JasperSoft would fix.